# Oracle Sql query to count time span with certain criteria

Tags: oracle, count, timespan

Oracle Sql query , I was trying to  count the grand total for time difference that is greater than 2, but when I tried this it just counted all the rows from the query instead of just the rows that have the criteria I was looking for. Anybody have an idea of what I am missing or a better approach . Thanks
This is my query

```
    select DC.CUST_FIRST_NAME,DC.CUST_LAST_NAME,oi.customer_id,oi.order_timestamp,oi.order_timestamp - LAG(oi.order_timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY oi.order_timestamp) AS "Difference(In Days)" , 
   (select Count('Elapsed Order Difference')
    from demo_orders oi,
    demo_customers dc
    where OI.CUSTOMER_ID = DC.CUSTOMER_ID 
    group by 'Elapsed Order Difference'
    having count('Elapsed Order Difference') > 3
    )Total
     from demo_orders oi,
    demo_customers dc
    where OI.CUSTOMER_ID = DC.CUSTOMER_ID


    Results
    CUST_FIRST_NAME CUST_LAST_NAME CUSTOMER_ID ORDER_TIMESTAMP      Difference(In Days)    TOTAL
    Eugene          Bradley             7       8/14/2013 5:59:11 PM                        10
    William         Hartsfield          2       8/28/2013 5:59:11 PM    14                 10
    Edward "Butch"  OHare               4       9/8/2013 5:59:11 PM     11                  10
     Edward         Logan               3       9/10/2013 5:59:11 PM    2                    10
     Edward         Logan               3       9/20/2013 5:59:11 PM    10                  10
     Albert         Lambert             6       9/25/2013 5:59:11 PM    5                   10
     Fiorello       LaGuardia           5       9/30/2013 5:59:11 PM    5                   10
    William         Hartsfield          2       10/8/2013 5:59:11 PM    8                   10
    John            Dulles              1       10/14/2013 5:59:11 PM   6                   10
    Eugene          Bradley             7       10/17/2013 5:59:11 PM   3                   10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but I think it might give you what you're after.

```
with raw_data as (
  select
    dc.cust_first_name, dc.cust_last_name,
    oi.customer_id, oi.order_timestamp,
    oi.order_timestamp - LAG(oi.order_timestamp) OVER
      (ORDER BY oi.order_timestamp) AS "Difference(In Days)",
    case
      when oi.order_timestamp - LAG(oi.order_timestamp)
        over (ORDER BY oi.order_timestamp) > 2 then 1
      else 0
    end as gt2
  from
    demo_orders oi,
    demo_customers dc
  where
    oi.customer_id = dc.customer_id  
)
select
  cust_first_name, cust_last_name,
  customer_id, order_timestamp,
  "Difference(In Days)",
  sum (gt2) over (partition by 1) as total
from raw_data
```

When you do `Count('Elapsed Order Difference')` above, you are counting every row, no matter what.  You could have put `count ('frog')` or `count (*)` and have gotten the same result.  The `having count > 3` was already satisfied since the count of all rows was 10.

In general, I'd try to avoid using a scalar for a field in a query as you have in your example.  I'm not saying it's never a good idea, but I would argue that there is usually a better way to do it.  With 10 rows, you'll hardly notice a performance difference, but as your datasets grow, this can create issues.

Expected output:

```
fn  ln  id  order date  dif total    
E   B   7   8/14/2014       8
W   H   2   8/28/2014   14  8
E   O   4   9/8/2014    11  8
E   L   3   9/10/2014   2   8
E   L   3   9/20/2014   10  8
A   L   6   9/25/2014   5   8
F   L   5   9/30/2014   5   8
W   H   2   10/8/2014   8   8
J   D   1   10/14/2014  6   8
E   B   7   10/17/2014  3   8
```

Comment: Gotcha,like you said it is going to count all 10 rows no matter what, so I figured well if the case statement is making the entries that are >2 a 1 and everything else a 0 then I can turn the Count(gt2) to sum(gt2) it gave me the 8 total. I tested this and it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: I messed up the first time and put count, which would give the exact same result as what you had...  I caught it on a second read.  Glad it worked.

Comment: Thanks again because this helped me with something I needed for work.